# Create Animation for Android 3.0 tablets

Tags: java, android

I was using [`android.view.animation`] to create animation for android 2.3. but on a large screen (as in tablets) the animations(Fade, Translate, Zoom, Rotate) are not smooth sometimes.
i want to explore [`android.animation`] for this. I want some suggestions for creating those basic animations in Android tablets. I am giving 2 examples that i need to solve using [`android.animation`]. When i was using the view.animation, i had a lot of problems. i want to know how to control the time in the seekbar. i want to use it in the tablets. 
also, 2 or more animations running in the same time. how to do it smoothly? [image: Problems]

Comment: One extremely important thing to do on Android 3.0 is to enable hardware acceleration as detailed at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html. This may explain why you are not getting smooth animations on your tablet.